# Keberos: how can I redirect a browser when it can't find a valid token?

Tags: spnego

To ask a browser to provide a Kerberos token, I send a 401 response with the "WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate" header.

If the browser can't find a Kerberos library, the user doesn't have a ticket, or the site isn't whitelisted, the browser wont' be able to send a Kerberos token, and will just display a 401 Unauthorized page. Is there a way I can redirect instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

401 response can contain a body - you can do a browser redirect using JS or meta tag

Comment: thanks - i was hoping to avoid using JS but the meta tag is a great idea